# Password Protect a "better-sqlite3" DB file

Tags: node.js, database, electron, password-protection, better-sqlite3

I have an electron-angular-node project which has few tables. I am using :

- electron version: 13.1.7
- Angular CLI: 12.0.2
- Node: 16.17.0
- Package Manager: npm 9.2.0
- OS version: Windows 10
- better-sqlite3: 7.4.6

I need to protect the DB file in case anybody wants to change data from the db.
I wants to lock it using some password and at the same time application should be able to use DB when needed.

My main question is:

Is it possible to password protect a better-sqlite3 DB file.
I'm searching for some free open source solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to password protect a better-sqlite3 DB file.

However, it is not a built-in feature of the database engine and would require additional code implementation.

One open source solution that could be used is SQLCipher, which is a free, open-source extension for SQLite that provides transparent 256-bit AES encryption of database files. SQLCipher can be integrated with better-sqlite3 to provide password protection for the DB file.

Regards!

Comment: I have seen documentation of "better-sqlite3-multiple-ciphers" but found not of much use.
I want to lock my DB file so that when any one tries to open it using DB browser for SQLite to see it content, they must enter a password first

Comment: @PiyushRoy I'm the maintainer of that package and it's odd that you couldn't follow through the documentation since it's right there on the front page as clear as day.
https://github.com/m4heshd/better-sqlite3-multiple-ciphers#encryption

Comment: I have tried "better-sqlite3-multiple-ciphers" and I know it encrypts the database but my as I have mentioned it in my previous comment, "when any one tries to open it using DB browser for SQLite to see it content, they must enter a password first" , but for the encrypted db file using "better-sqlite3-multiple-ciphers" ,  DB browser for SQLite is giving me a prompt :-
                          Could not open database file.
                          Reason: File is not a database.
I want when I tries to open it, it should ask for a password which should be 1 that was used while creating DB.

Comment: @PiyushRoy The problem you're having is also mentioned very thoroughly right on the front page of the documentation. You need to read a lot more about these different encryption schemes and the software you use. Did you even read the section of the documentation I linked above?